# Android layout scaling (for elements of a given size in dp)

Tags: android, layout, scale, dimensions

Three FrameLayout's of different background colors to form a **strip**.
Each FrameLayout has the size specified in dp.

[[image: 1]]

The **strip** is long and does not fit on the screen.
How to scale the strip to maintain the aspect ratio and without changing the dimensions dp?

[[image: 2]]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:measureAllChildren="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layoutDirection="ltr"
        android:rotation="0">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:background="#508da6"
         />
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:background="#494949"
        />
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:background="#ff0000"
       />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Assigning dp for layout width is not a good idea since you will run intro trouble with different screen sizes, you should use android:layout_weight see Anonymous' answer.

Comment: Actually for that I asked the question about scaling ;)

Answer by Anonymous is not suitable since the height remains dp, but should be in proportion to the width!

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that in the manifest, I will advise you to use Anonymous' answer and then get the width and calculate the height programatically.

Comment: This library might help https://github.com/intuit/sdp

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to inflate three whole FrameLayout just for that.View will do just fine. Also you should not give fixed widths since there is no way to make it work for all screen sizes.

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:measureAllChildren="true">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layoutDirection="ltr"
        android:rotation="0">

        <View
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#508da6"
            />
        <View
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#494949"
            />
        <View
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

set height on runtime

```
 LinearLayout stripLayout = (LinearLayout)findVieById(R.id.strip);
  stripLayout .getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalFocusChangeListener(new OnGlobalFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalFocusChanged(View oldFocus, View newFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int width = stripLayout .getWidth();
            int height = //calculate your height//
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = stripLayout .getLayoutParams();
            params.height = height;
            stripLayout .setLayoutParams(params);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) { stripLayout .getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);   } 
            else { stripLayout .getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);  }
        }
    });
```

Comment: This scheme is not suitable for me. I need to be sure to keep the original dimensions in the dp for each of the 200/400/240.

Comment: And what's going to happen when your app is installed on a device with screen width less than 200+400+240 dp ????

Comment: The strip will be proportionally smaller in width and height. what is the problem?
Read my question carefully.

" How to scale the strip to maintain the aspect ratio and without changing the dimensions dp?"

Comment: You can't scale without changing the dimensions dp, not sure what you mean there.

Comment: well it wasn't THAT clear but ok...Then you use the layout I wrote for you and then set the height on runtime to whatever height you need based on the width of the screen.